# JavaScript to only allow numbers and certain length and no periods

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

I need help with a piece of JavaScript. I have this code:

```
<script>
function FilterInput(event) {
    var keyCode = ('which' in event) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    isNotWanted = (keyCode == 69);
    return !isNotWanted;
};
function handlePaste(e) {
    var clipboardData, pastedData;
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text').toUpperCase();
    if (pastedData.indexOf('E') > -1) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
</script>
```

I would like to limit the user's input to only 5 digits. For example, for this entry box, I'd like no more than five numbers to be allowed (12345 for example) and no periods:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Customer Number</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i></span>
      <input name="CustomerNumber" type="number" class="form-control" onkeydown="return FilterInput(event)" onpaste="handlePaste(event)" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.form-group -->
</div>
<!-- /.col -->
```

How would I achieve this? I know for

```
type="text"
```

it allows limiting spaces by using "maxlength."

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I'd strongly urge you to consider a framework (like jQuery) and leverage validation tools provided by the framework, or validation plugins targeted for that framework.  This example is relatively simple ...but there are many other use cases that are complex enough that you might not want to "reinvent the wheel"...

Comment: Do you have an example of how I'd achieve this in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to trap the input, check if it passes your validation checks, and if so, proceed, if not, set it to the last known good value, like so:

```js
var oldValue = "";
// listen for "input" event, since that handles all keypresses as well as cut/paste
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener('input', function (event) {
  var input = event.target;
  if (validateInput(input.value)) {
    // update old value with new value
    oldValue = input.value;
  }
  else {
    // set value to last known valid value
    input.value = oldValue;
  }
});

function validateInput(str) {
  // check length, if is a number, if is whole number, if no periods
  return /^[0-9]{0,5}$/.test(str);
}
```

```html
Test: <input type="text" id="myInput"/><br/>
Try typing/pasting invalid input
```

Comment: this needed a little work, as it threw a type error and a ")" is missing error where your target ID contain any special character. I ended up adding the following lines to fix both: var elmId = "id-with-hyphen";
  function updateHTML(elmId, value) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(elmId);
        if(typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem !== null) {
            elem.innerHTML = value;
        }
       }

Comment: @Ojchris I'm really confused as to what you mean by this. The code I posted is a live working example with no syntax errors. An HTML element with an ID with a hyphen is still valid to pass into `document.getElementById` so I'm not sure why that was throwing an error for you. The other thing I'm confused about is why you're setting innerHTML on an `input` element. The correct way to set the value of the element is through the `value` property. Unless you're not setting it for an `input` element? Can you please elaborate on what exactly you used this solution for?

Comment: I upvoted before commenting. using your snippet as is, I got "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null" in console. Digging into this error I found for some weird reason the js script was loading faster than the html even though  the script was placed before the body tag. so I use the updateHTML to do a null check. My input has an id jade-field-another-try-0-value, so after resolving the typerror, I got a ')' missing syntax error. var elm = "edit-field-another-try-0-value" helped in resolving that. Between, am not a Js expert I might just have hacked my way :)

Comment: @Ojchris *"for some weird reason the js script was loading faster than the html even though the script was placed before the body tag"* - that is the expected behavior. If you register an event handler prior to the element being rendered (i.e. JS before <body>) you will see this error every time. This is why JS should be loaded after the <body> tag, and inside a "on document ready" function callback.

Comment: mhodges actually meant before the body CLOSING tag :)

Comment: @Ojchris Ah, gotcha. Unfortunately it still doesn't guarantee that DOM elements are fully rendered before the JS runs and the event listener tries to register. The best bet is to always use a document ready function, even if putting your scripts at the end of your <body> tag.

Comment: yes you're right on ready(). Just to clarify for others, I'm working within Drupal and evidently there is a time lag in form rendering vs other elements on the  page. Typically you shouldn't have my experience. mhoges should work readily

Answer (score 1):

all the answers given here previously before mine are all outdated previous
I think solving this question is best answered by

1. Javascript slice is used to maintain character length
2. Javascript replace to maintain only numbers are taken
3. javascript oninput event to prevent the user does not use copy and paste to inject / input invalid character javascript.

```html
<script>
function validate(field) {
   let val = field.value;
   let data = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
   field.value = data.slice(0,16);
}
</script>
<label for="atmno">Payment card Number</label>
<input name="atmno" type="text" oninput="validate(this)">
```

I briefly described the answer on an article I wrote here: https://shopinson.com/javascript/javascript-validates-payment-card-number/

Answer (score 0):

You can run a validation check in your `filterInput` method.

```js
document.querySelector('.input-group .form-control').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
var keyCode = ('which' in event) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
  isNotWanted = (keyCode == 69);

  if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);
  }

  return !isNotWanted;
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Customer Number</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i></span>
      <input maxlength="5" name="CustomerNumber" type="number" class="form-control"  required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.form-group -->
</div>
<!-- /.col -->
```

Comment: returning a value from event listeners isn't standardized - it may behave differently across different browsers.

Comment: I tried the code snippet. It still allows the letter "e" and periods

Answer (score 0):

Well you could instead of choosing a number type input, use a text type input, where the maxlength attribute works and throw an error with JavaScript if the value is not a number. Like,

```
if(isNaN(input.value)){ // error code here }
```

Comment: `input.value` will always be a string. You should probably check if `!isNaN(+input.value)` instead. Also, making sure the number is whole (no periods), you can do a bunch of different ways, one easy one being `if (+input.value === Math.floor(+input.value))`

Comment: Why the + before input.value?

Comment: I suppose you don't need it on the `isNaN` check, but for the second check, you do. See my post for the easiest way to check (with regex) for the valid input

Answer (score 0):

A pure js and dom manipulation solution

Adding an Id attribute for simplicity

```
<input type="number" id="in" />
```

We're going to listen for the keypress event and do nothing if the max length is met or a period is entered, i'm using 5 as the max.

```
let input = document.getElementById('in');
input.addEventListener('keypress',function test(e){
    if(input.value.length==5 || e.key=='.')
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Would I wrap `let input = document.getElementById('in');
input.addEventListener('keypress',function test(e){
    if(input.value.length==5 || e.key=='.')
        e.preventDefault();
});` in `<script></script>` ?

Comment: Yeah, in a script tag anywhere after the element is defined e.g. after your body or preferably, an external js file, either way you should be fine